# Xamarin iOS : Tool exited with code: 1. Output: fatal error: lipo: can't write to output file

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to build the Xamarin.iOS project in VS 2017. However, whenever I am trying to generate .ipa file OR build the project it is giving me following error.

> Tool exited with code: 1. Output: fatal error: lipo: can't write to output file: bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/MyiOS.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyiOS.lipo (Undefined error: 0)
>   error: lipo:

I have tried cleaning and rebuild also but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Disable  `device -specific builds` for Release Configuration, and delete `bin`, `obj` folders.

Comment: Any updates for fixing this issues. I also struck with that from long time.

Comment: Another problem could be that debug files can't be written to the machine because there's not enough space. I cleared approximately 2 GB on my build machine (Macbook) and the error disappeared.